# Scope from controller does not pass to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a html like this :

```
    <div id="create-group" ng-controller="groupCreateController">
       <div id="container">
        <h1>Create group</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><input placeholder="Group Name.." ng-model="group.name"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label>Group Description : </label>
                <textarea ng-model="group.description">     </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <usermgr-permission-list group="group"></usermgr-permission-list>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" ng-click="btnSave_click($event)">SAVE</button>

            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <usermgr-user-list group="group"></usermgr-user-list>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My controller is :

```
(function (module) {
'use strict';

module.controller('groupCreateController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, userGroupService, $mdDialog) {


    $scope.group = [];
    $scope.init = function () {
    if ($routeParams.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            //edit mode
            // $scope.trans.heading = 'Edit Release';
            // $scope.trans.saveBtn = 'Save';
            var id = parseInt($routeParams.id);
            getUserGroup(id);
        } else {
            $scope.group[0].id = 0;
            $scope.group[0].permissions = [];
            $scope.assignedPermissions = [];
            $scope.enrolledUsers = [];
            $scope.group[0].users = [];
            $scope.group[0].name = '';
            $scope.group[0].description = '';
        }
    };

    function getUserGroup(id) {
        userGroupService.getbyid(id).then(function (info) {

            if (info !== undefined && info.id === id) {
                $scope.group[0].id = info.id;
                $scope.group[0].name = info.name;
                $scope.group[0].description = info.description;
                console.log($scope.group);
                // $rootScope.$broadcast('rCube-user-mgt-users-list', info.id);
                // $rootScope.$broadcast('rCube-user-mgt-permissions-list', info.id);
            }
            else {

            }
        }).catch(function (exception) {
            console.error(exception);

        });
    }



    $scope.init();


});

})(angular.module('r-cube-user-mgt.user-group'));
```

I have two custom directives in the first block of code for user permissions and users. The group scope that i pass with the directive does not contain the values i put in the getUserGroup(id) function. The group name and group description shows up so the scope.group in the controller is filled, however thats not the case once i pass it to my directives. here is the directives code as well :

permissions list :

```
 (function (module) {
    'use strict';
    module.directive('usermgrPermissionList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
             scope:{
                 group: '='
            },
            controller: function ($scope, permissionService) {
                 $scope.updatedPermissions=[];
                console.log($scope.group); //it doesnt have the values from the controller ..
              if (!$scope.group.hasOwnProperty('permissions')) {
                    $scope.group.permissions = [];
                }

                function getData() {
                    console.log("inside getDAta for permission list" + $scope.group.id;

                    permissionService.getPermissionsFiltered($scope.group.id).then(function (info) {
                        if (info && info.length > 0) {
                            console.log(info);
                            $scope.group.permissions = info.map(function (a, index, array) {
                                return {
                                    id: a.id,
                                    name: a.name,
                                    description: a.description,
                                    assigned: a.assigned 
                                };  
                            }); 
                        } 
                    }).catch(function (exception) {
                        console.error(exception);

                    });
                } //end of getData()

                $scope.init = function () {
                    getData();
                };


                $scope.init();
            },
            templateUrl: 'r-cube-user-mgt/permission/list/list.tpl.html'
        };
    });
    })(angular.module('r-cube-user-mgt.permission'));
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot assign property to an array like this `$scope.group.id = 0;` 
either make `$scope.group` object

```
$scope.group = {};
```

or add properties to an index

```
 $scope.group = [];
  $scope.init = function () {
    if ($routeParams.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            //edit mode
            // $scope.trans.heading = 'Edit Release';
            // $scope.trans.saveBtn = 'Save';
            var id = parseInt($routeParams.id);
            getUserGroup(id);
        } else {
            $scope.group[0].id = 0;
            $scope.group[0].permissions = [];
            $scope.assignedPermissions = [];
            $scope.enrolledUsers = [];
            $scope.group[0].users = [];
            $scope.group[0].name = '';
            $scope.group[0].description = '';
        }
 };
```

Comment: i changed it like you mentioned. But now Im getting a error :  

TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Comment: change the `getUserGroup(id)` content using `0` index also

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: where is the service

Comment: it  basically gets the group name, description and Id from the database. That is working and im able to fill the textboxes. However, that group scope when i send it to my user permission directive shows length as = 0 and the name , description and id are not there ...

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue by adding broadcast to send the id when the directive loads. This worked!

in the Group controller i add broadcast and send the group.id

```
    function getUserGroup(id) {
                    userGroupService.getbyid(id).then(function (info) {

                        if (info !== undefined && info.id === id) {
                            $scope.group.id = info.id;
                            $scope.group.name = info.name;
                            $scope.group.description = info.description;
                            console.log($scope.group);                                                      
                     $rootScope.$broadcast(rCubeTopics.userMgtPermissionLoadData, $scope.group.id);
                        }

                    }).catch(function (exception) {
                        console.error(exception);

                    });
                }
```

and in the permission directive get that broadcast :

```
      $scope.$on(rCubeTopics.userMgtPermissionLoadData, function (event, id) {
                    console.log($scope.group.id);
                    getData();
                });
```